# Unintended typing into textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, panel

So I have created 2 games (tic tac toe and ping pong). Both games first gave "login" panel and then actual "game" panel. Now I realized that if I press any key on keyboard it goes into text box which is login panel which is hidden when game panel is visible. What could cause that ?

I tried disabling text box and that would work but then if I press key I get that windows error sound.

For code I cant paste it both games have about 600 lines of code I'm hoping that there is something that should be done when you switch panels.

Comment: The login has focus, so it takes the key press. Disabling it removes that focus, and since no element *has* focus* you get the error sound. Thats all expected behavior, what are you asking?

Comment: set TabIndex or foces to different control, disable other control afterwards

Comment: A better option would be to use two different forms, one for logging in and one for the actual game window.

Answer (score 0):

Set the focus of the control to the textbox you want the cursor to start in.